# Can attr_accessible accept objects as opposed to model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to make sense of a pre-built app in which:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :status,:user,:friend
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User",:foreign_key => "friend_id"
end
```

I am confused by the `attr_accessible` part where he has supplied `:user` and `:friend` because they are not attributes in the friendship model. Is that just a short way for writing `:user_id` or `friend_id` or is he actually supplying the `:user` object and the `:friend` object? if they are indeed objects, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a user_id or friend_id, it allows you to assign an user or a friend:

```
Friendship.create!(:status=>"active", :user=>current_user, :friend=>@friend)
```

with `attr_accessible :user_id,:friend_id`, you would do this:

```
Friendship.create!(:status=>"active", :user_id=>current_user.id, :friend_id=>@friend.id)
```

In short, both ways effectively save user_id and friend_id.  Just different ways to do it.

Note: You should only make accessible the attributes you want to assign, otherwise you're potentially creating mass assignment vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a short way of writing `user_id`. `attr_accessible` means, that you can mass assign a while user when creating a friendship. This means that **with** `attr_accessible :status,:user,:friend` you can do

```
Friendship.create! user: user1, friend: friend1
```

**without** that `attr_accessible` an error would be thrown, because the mass assignment of user and friend is disabled